# Microsoft translator changing phrase where there are html spans

Tags: microsoft-translator

Plain english sentence is:

> While in 5th direct and ready for the downshift to 4th overdrive, push
>   the range preselection lever down.

Converts to French correctly as:

> Alors que dans le 5ème direct et prêt pour le downshift à la 4ème
>   overdrive, pousser **le levier de présélection de gamme vers le bas.**

However, when including html (&textType=html), the phrase doesn't have the same meaning:

```
While in 5th direct and ready for the downshift to <span data-id="xyz123">4th overdrive</span>, push the range preselection lever down.
```

Translates to:

> Alors que dans le 5ème direct et prêt pour le downshift à 4e
>   overdrive, pousser **la gamme levier de présélection duvet.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tags are considered an additional token in the sentence. Similar effect as punctuation, both having an effect on the translation.